# Cannot load shared object when installing package "car" in R

Tags: r, macos, r-package

I used `install.package('car')` in R to install the car package, but failed, showing that the required packages are failed to load. Required packages are:

```
  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
         binary source needs_compilation
minqa     1.2.4  1.2.5              TRUE
nloptr    2.0.0  2.0.3              TRUE
quantreg   5.88   5.94              TRUE
lme4     1.1-28 1.1-30              TRUE
car      3.0-12  3.1-1             FALSE
```

So I tried `install.packages('minqa')` , but also failed, messages are:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘minqa’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 
无法载入共享目标对象‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/00LOCK-minqa/00new/minqa/libs/minqa.so’：:
    dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/00LOCK-minqa/00new/minqa/libs/minqa.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_bobyqa_'

错误: 载入失败
停止执行

ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/minqa’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status
```

My computer is MacBook with M1 pro chip, with **macOS Ventura 13.0** and installed **Xcode** and **gfortran-ARM-12.1-Monterey**, with no other settings.

Extra info:

I though that there might be some wrong settings of the environment path, so I tried `Sys.getenv("PATH")` and `Sys.which("stats.dll")` , results are:

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hansondai/Applications/quarto/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/texbin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS"
```

```
> Sys.which("stats.dll")
stats.dll
    ""
```

Actually the ERROR of cannot load shared object  happened several times when I install different packages. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Is Rcpp installed? If not, you may need to install this first. My usual package install error trouble shooting: Say no to `Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)`.  Run `.libPaths()` then go to the directory, and check you have access. Manually remove previous installs. Install the dependencies of the troublesome package before installing the troublesome package.

Comment: @Isaiah, post as answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by using `conda`. You could try `conda install -c conda-forge r-minqa`.

However, if you're not using `conda`, I saw when I was installing the problematic package through condo, that it installed `libgit2`, and the r-packages `credentials`, `ca-certificates` and `certifi`. I'm suspecting that the root problem was the fact that I was missing `libgit2`. I believe you can also install this package with `brew` if you have that.

In addition, for me the error output also suggested to install certain packages through `brew` (or any other platform). I don't know if you checked that?

Let me know if this helps!